# Can I use the context variables in the conditions for the nodes in the dialog flow in the Watson Conversation?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Can I use the context variables in the conditions for the nodes in the dialog flow in the Watson Conversation?

In the case I try it:

if condition: `context.variable !== 'undefined'` the conversation will flow, else, the conversation will show some text.

How do it?

**I try it:**

[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7JXo.png)

And the conversation does not flow... and the intent flow to `intent.confidence < 0.3` i've created

Obs.: My `context.variable`e just get some Data with `regex`, if user dont type correct, the conversation flow will display another message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue may be with your regex. You have a dangling * at the end. It should be:

```
  "context": {
    "xxx": "<? input.text.extract('^[^\d].*?[\d]{11}.*?$',0) ?>"
  },
```

Before the variable is check you can use the following condition.

```
input.text.matches('^[^\\d].*?\\d{11}.*?')
```

When checking to see if the variable is set, you only need to have a condition as follows:

```
$xxx
```

Sample conversation script: http://pastebin.com/HuCJckry